# What's the meaning of という in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm going crazy over this, i would like to understand the meaning of という in this sentence and i can't find anywhere a specific answer:

昔の中国 では、珍しい貝殻がお金として使われていたということである。

I know the meaning of という but i can't understand its role in this sentence, could someone help me? Very thank you!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19474/5010